# How to create a table with SQLAlchemy (asyncio)?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to create a table, only one, not `create_all` (though this MetaData method works), with the async SQLALchemy engine. Here's what I've tried. To be honest, I've tried a lot more, but all the options did not work for me.

```
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, BigInteger, Float, MetaData
from sqlalchemy.schema import DropTable, CreateTable
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import create_async_engine

engine = create_async_engine(*HERE IS MY URL*, echo=True)
metadata_obj = MetaData()

async def create_price_timestamp_table(table_name):
    table = Table(table_name, metadata_obj, 
        Column('timestamp', BigInteger, primary_key=True, nullable=False),
        Column('price', Float, nullable=False),
        keep_existing=True,
    )
    async with engine.begin() as conn:
        await conn.run_sync(CreateTable(table))
    return table
```

The error I get:

```
 File "c:\Users\development\Desktop\websockets\websockets.py", line 44, in create_price_timestamp_table
    
await conn.run_sync(CreateTable(table))

  File "C:\Users\development\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\ext\asyncio\engine.py", line 548, in run_sync

return await greenlet_spawn(fn, conn, *arg, **kw)

  File "C:\Users\development\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\_concurrency_py3k.py", line 115, in greenlet_spawn

result = context.switch(*args, **kwargs)

`TypeError: DDLElement.__call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'bind'`
```

The same stuff when I try to drop the table with sqlalchemy.schema.DropTable() method.

What would be the correct way of doing it?

Comment: Pass `table.create` to `conn.run_sync`

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, however, when I try the suggested way, I am getting

```
AttributeError: 'AsyncSession' object has no attribute '_run_ddl_visitor'
```

The code is working when using non-async methods, also when I try to remove this line with await, no errors are thrown.

Currently NOT-WORKING async snippet for the creation of the table:

```
from sqlalchemy.schema import CreateTable
from sqlalchemy import Table

async with async_session() as session:
    meta = MetaData()
    new_dataset_table = Table(
            f'{data.name}',
            meta,
            *(column for column in columns),
        )
    await session.run_sync(new_dataset_table.create(session))
```

I come up with this WORKING async solution, however, I believe there is a better way to achieve the same result.

```
from sqlalchemy.schema import CreateTable
from sqlalchemy import Table

async with async_session() as session:
    meta = MetaData()
    new_dataset_table = Table(
        f'{data.name}',
        meta,
        *(column for column in columns),
    )
    create_expression = CreateTable(new_dataset_table)
    await session.execute(create_expression)
```